# Why is the array losing its values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to build a list using the twitch api that updates the list when the user wants to see who is streaming and who isn't. For example, when I press the offline button, the list should only contain users whose 'stream' value is null. Here's my html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul class="menubar">
      <li><a id="all" href="#">All</a></li>
      <li><a id="online" href="#">Online</a></li>
      <li><a id="offline" href="#">Offline</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="users">
      <ul class="members">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my javascript (with jQuery already imported):

```
var users = ["MedryBW", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx","RobotCaleb","thomasballinger","noobs2ninjas","beohoff"];

var listOffline = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each(users, function(i , val){
      $('.members').append("<li>" + val + "</li>"); 
  }); 

  $('#offline').on('click', function(){
     $.each(users, function(i , val){
       $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + val , function(data){
          if(data['stream'] == null) {
            listOffline.push(val);
          }
       });
     });
    $('.members li').remove();
    $.each(listOffline, function(i , val) {
      $('.members').append("<li>" + val + "</li>");
    });

  });

});
```

Why does the 'listOffline' array lose the values that are pushed into it at the end of the first .each block in the $('#offline').on('click') function? Any help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to append the list before it's populated. Because $.getJSON is an asynchronous function. Also note that you need to empty the list by calling the `remove` function before looping through your users.

You should append the list in the success callback function

```
 $('#offline').on('click', function(){
 $('.members li').remove();
     $.each(users, function(i , val){
       $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + val , function(data){
          if(data['stream'] == null) {
            listOffline.push(val);
             $('.members').append("<li>" + val + "</li>");
          }
       });
     });
```

Comment: This is close, but calling the `$('.members li').remove();` will result in only adding the last item to the list (since all the others were just removed)

Comment: I just edited it and it's now removing the members list before calling $.each

Comment: it's better, but you're going to end up with a list like "MedryBW", "MedryBW", "freecodecamp", "MedryBW", "freecodecamp", "storbeck" (lots of repeats) since the entire array is appended to the `ul` for each loop - you cannot loop through `listOffline` and append to the DOM in this callback.

Comment: @pherris , you're absolutely right. edited again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the $.getJson is async, this means that your last each loop is reached and executed before all results are returned from the server and so you're processing a partial list.

To verify this add the following printouts:

In the block that handles the $.getJson response, before the condition:

```
console.log('user ', val, ' retrieved);
```

and just after your last each loop:

```
console.log('offline list processed');
```

You will probably see that users are retrieved (+ processed and pushed) after your list is processed.

If this is the case you can do one of the following:

- Use promises and perform your last each loop only when they are done
- Or even simpler, when you get a result, instead of pushing it into an array, just do:

  ```
   $('.members').append("<li>" + val + "</li>");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The `getJSON` call is async, so the code in the callback is executed after the next `.each`. Try moving the last `.each` inside of the callback:

```
$('#offline').on('click', function(){
   $('.members li').remove();
   $.each(users, function(i , val){
     $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + val).done(function(data){
       if (data['stream'] == null) {
         listOffline.push(val);
         $('.members').append("<li>" + val + "</li>");
       }
   });
 });
```

You can also use the deferred `.done` to keep things a little cleaner.